# Limit points of $(0, \ 1]$

Tags: general-topology

I am reading the section in Munkres about limit points, and it says that for the subset $(0, \ 1]$ of the real line, any point of $[0, \ 1]$ acts as a limit point, including, for example, $0.5$. However, if the definition of a limit point is that every neighbourhood containing the limit point intersects the subset at some point other than the limit point itself, couldn't I just define an open set as the interval $(0.5 \ - \ \epsilon, \ 0.5 \ + \ \epsilon)$, for some infinitesimal value $\epsilon$ to contain only the point $0.5$, and therefore not follow the criteria for a limit point? Am I misunderstanding how open intervals can be defined?

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is defined to be a *strictly positive real number*, there is no such thing as an infinitesimal real number, thus your interval contains lots of other numbers besides $0.5$, e.g. it contains $0.5 + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

Comment: @Thoth So to clarify, even if I try to construct an open interval like I have done with the $\epsilon$, there will always be a smaller $\epsilon$, therefore those smaller values (like $\epsilon/2 \ + \ 0.5$) are included in the original subset and the neighbourhood, making the point a limit point?

Comment: that's correct    .

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Notation.** "$(x,y)$" is notation for "$\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}:x<\xi<y\}$."

**Terminology.** Fix a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Say  $x$ is a *limit point* of $S$ if for each positive real $\varepsilon>0$, the interval $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ intersects $S\setminus{\{x\}}$.

**Remark.** Infinitesimals are not real numbers.